# Getting NoClassDefFoundError during IBM liberty server start up

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am getting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal` during the IBM liberty server starting up. How to resolve this error? Is there any dependency jar missing? Please find the full error trace as below:

```
Launching EBCIRIX01 (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.8/wlp-1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_80-b15 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server EBCIRIX01 has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/8.5.5.8/lafiles/en.html
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[ERROR   ] CWWKS9582E: The [defaultSSLConfig] sslRef attributes required by the orb element with the defaultOrb id have not been resolved within 10 seconds. As a result, the applications will not start. Ensure that you have included a keyStore element and that Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) is configured correctly. If the sslRef is defaultSSLConfig, then add a keyStore element with the id defaultKeyStore and a password.
[ERROR   ] CWWKS9660E: The orb element with the defaultOrb id attribute requires a user registry but no user registry became available within 10 seconds.   As a result, no application will start. Ensure that you have configured an appropriate user registry in the server.xml file.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application ebcirix01 has not started in 30.052 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [jdbc-4.1, localConnector-1.0, servlet-3.1, jsp-2.3, jndi-1.0, el-3.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server EBCIRIX01 is ready to run a smarter planet.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/ebcirix01/
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the file:/C:/dev/workspaces/RixJava06032017/LocalTestEnvironment/usr/servers/EBCIRIX01/apps/ebcirix01.war.xml location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.persistence.PersistenceContext annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the file:/C:/dev/workspaces/RixJava06032017/LocalTestEnvironment/usr/servers/EBCIRIX01/apps/ebcirix01.war.xml location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$CompositeELResolverImpl class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/el/ScopeELResolver
[WARNING ] CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$CompositeELResolverImpl class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/el/ScopeELResolver
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:318)
    at [internal classes]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:95)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:44)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:510)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:450)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:257)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:560)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:577)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:212)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:103)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.getContext(LogAdapter.java:39)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    at [internal classes]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2389)
    at [internal classes]

11:14:35.626 [LargeThreadPool-thread-33] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [wsjar:file:/C:/.m2/com/ikea/ebcframework/ebcfwk-webapp-core/7.0.1/ebcfwk-webapp-core-7.0.1.jar!/com/ikea/ebcframework/web/javafwk-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494) [ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) [com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.3.1_1.0.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:332) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1423) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:1180) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:1148) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1054) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6448) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:446) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:441) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:981) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startModule(WebContainer.java:805) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.web.internal.WebModuleHandlerImpl.deployModule(WebModuleHandlerImpl.java:102) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager.war_1.0.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModule(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:870) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module_1.0.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModules(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:830) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module_1.0.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:817) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module_1.0.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.war.internal.WARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(WARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:66) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager.war_1.0.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:139) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1168) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:781) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager_1.1.11.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:318) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:262) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:411) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:383) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.f
indClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:433) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:267) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:411) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:383) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:318) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:262) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:411) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:383) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[ebcirix01.war.xml:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    ... 38 more

[ERROR   ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [javafwk] in application [ebcirix01]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [wsjar:file:/C:/.m2/com/ikea/ebcframework/ebcfwk-webapp-core/7.0.1/ebcfwk-webapp-core-7.0.1.jar!/com/ikea/ebcframework/web/javafwk-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:332)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:318)
    at [internal classes]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 19 more

[ERROR   ] SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [javafwk]: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:401)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [wsjar:file:/C:/.m2/com/ikea/ebcframework/ebcfwk-webapp-core/7.0.1/ebcfwk-webapp-core-7.0.1.jar!/com/ikea/ebcframework/web/javafwk-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:332)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:318)
    at [internal classes]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 19 more

[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application ebcirix01 started in 74.331 seconds.
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing Xerxes libraries from your application. The required class is in `xml-apis.jar`, you need to add it to the `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: The runtime only provides defined APIs based on the features you have provisioned. Gas is right above that you need to include that JAR into your app or as a shared library if the application needs those classes.

Comment: Thanks Gas and ewhoch the error is not coming now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing Xerxes libraries from your application. The required class is in xml-apis.jar, you need to add it to the WEB-INF/lib or use shared library.